# How to customize Today button in Kendo schedular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-scheduler

I am working on **kendo.ui.Scheduler**. I want to customize **Today** button. If I click on Today button it navigates to the current date of local system.
I want to navigate to the date which I have given in **date** property of **calenderoption**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way of doing so would be to hook the the click event on the button as follows

```
$(".k-nav-today a").on("click",function(e){ 
     var scheduler = $("#myscheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
     var mydate = new Date("2013/6/6") // retrieve the date you want to set
     scheduler.date(mydate) // whatever date you wish too
     return false;
});
```

I'm unsure exactly what you mean by calenderoption however but I hope this helps, I've used jquery but I imagine it'll be quite east to translate into angular/other.

Comment: calenderoption is model data for k-options

Comment: Can you please help to show currentTimeMarker as per my date and time

Answer (score 0):

You can use an internal method inside the initialization:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    // ...
    navigate: function(e) {
        if (e.action === "today") {
            var mydate = new Date("2019/1/1");
            this.date(mydate);
        }
    }
});
```